# Unable to access node app from K8s cluster

Tags: node.js, api, kubernetes

I have deployed a very simple node application to a minikube cluster. I created the docker image and everything is working fine while in the container. When I build it in the k8s cluster, I can see the deployment is working.

I am trying to access the node application through a load balancer using the minikube IP and port provided when running "kubectl get svc". I know I'm doing this part correct at least...

When I try to access the URL and check the network tab, the request never finishes and just stays pending.

The node app is a very simple API I made just for testing so I use the route /posts when trying to access the application. It should return some JSON and this all works from the container. It all just stops working while in the cluster.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: server-deployment
spec: 
  replicas: 3
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      targets: nodes
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        targets: nodes
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - name: server
          image: brandonjones085/mean-backend
          ports: 
            - containerPort: 3000

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-load
spec:
  selector:
  
    targets: nodes
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: Provide more details about the kubernetes cluster. Is it minikube?

Comment: Where is your minikube running? Mac?

Comment: Yes, it is a minikube cluster so single node. Right now, I only have a single service which is the load balancer for the node app, and a single deployment with 1 replica, which is the node app. The minikube ip is http://192.168.99.100 and the load balancer port is 31334 so I'm trying to access the url http://192.168.99.100:31334/posts. "posts" is the route which I use for the api. It all works great while in a container, the issue only begins once in k8s.

Comment: The `LoadBalancer` service type doesn't work by default, on `minikube`. To make it work, you need to first run, this command `minikube tunnel` https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/

Comment: I have minikube running on virtualbox on my machine and I'm running ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Just like @Hackerman described, if you using the [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/) type of service you need to use `minikube tunnel`. You can follow the [example](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#example). This type of service is usually meant to provision a provider Load Balancer, for example, an [AWS ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/). But in the case of minikube there is no external provider and you need to trick it into thinking there is one.

Basically, you need to run it before you create your Deployment.

On a separate terminal:

```sh
minikube tunnel
```

Then apply your manifest YAML file that includes your definition in your question:

```sh
kubectl apply -f <your-deployment>.yaml
```

✌️

Comment: So I started using the LoadBalancer service just for testing. Originally, I was using a ClusterIP. I had a frontend deployment and a backend deployment. The frontend was using a NodePort service. When I would ssh into the front end pod, and "curl http://backend:3000/posts", I would get the same results. The request just hangs and never responds.

Comment: Yeah. I'm still getting the same result. I even tried uninstalling/reinstalling minikube.

Comment: what's the output for `minikube tunnel`?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Rico answer: there are two ways to access applications deployed on minikube.

**First**- [using NodePort](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#nodeport-access). When exposing application using `NodePort` service type you are able to access it by executing `minikube service list` and accessing URL shown by the output- it is result of `minikube ip` and nodeport. Output will be similar to this:

```
|-------------|------------|----------------------------|-----|
|  NAMESPACE  |    NAME    |        TARGET PORT         | URL |
|-------------|------------|----------------------------|-----|
|             |
| default     | nginx      | http://192.168.39.22:30345 |
|             |
|-------------|------------|----------------------------|-----|
```

**Second option** is by using [`minikube tunnel`](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#example) command. It assigns externalIP to application exposed by`LoadBalancer` service type. When trying to access it `minikube tunnel` has to be running and in separate terminal you can access it using `externalIP:port`. Example output of `minikube tunnel`:

```
$minikube tunnel
Status:
        machine: minikube
        pid: 9284
        route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 192.168.39.22
        minikube: Running
        services: [backend-load]
```

Then you can check external IP assigned to this service by running `kubectl get service`:

```
kubectl get svc
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
backend-load   LoadBalancer   10.100.120.115   10.100.120.115   3000:31676/TCP   110s
```

so in this example application will be accessible under `10.100.120.115:3000`.

Comment: So I figured part of the issue out. It was something with virtualbox causing the issue. When I setup the cluster on GKE it all worked perfectly.